# Showing convergence of a series almost everywhere

Tags: measure-theory

If $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k$ is convergent series of positive terms and $(\alpha_k)_{k\in \Bbb N}$ is a sequence of real numbers, then the series $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{a_k}{\sqrt{|x-\alpha_k|}}$$ converges for almost all $x\in \Bbb R$.

The natural thing to do is integrate the series however $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{a_k}{\sqrt{|x-\alpha_k|}}$ does not need to converge. I'm trying to partition $\Bbb R$ to measurable subset with finite measure of which the integral will be finite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't integrate over the whole line. Integrate over the interval $[-M,M]$:
$$ \int_{[-M,M]} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k}{\sqrt{|x - \alpha_k|}} \, dx = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k \int_{[-M,M]} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x - \alpha_k|}}\, dx.$$ The last integral does not exceed $4 \sqrt{M}$, so that the series has finite integral on $[-M,M]$, and is thus finite almost everywhere there. This implies (arguing over a sequence of $M$'s) that the series converges almost everywhere on the line.

Comment: I was stuck on finding a bound, so I abandoned the idea of using the interval $[-n,n]$. How do I show $4\sqrt{M}$ is the bound?

Comment: More or less direct computation. If $\alpha_k = 0$ you have $$\int_{[-M,M]} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}} \, dx = 4 \sqrt{M}.$$ For $\alpha_k \not= 0$ it requires just a little more effort.

Comment: Could you possibly give me the steps because there are so many ways I could begin with this, and in most of them I end up complicating the problem. Should I start by splitting the integral on where $x-\alpha_k$ is positive or negative?