# prove $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha\sqrt{n |x-x_n|}} $ converges almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $ \{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty \subset \mathbb{R} $ be a sequence. Prove for $\alpha>1$ that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^\alpha\sqrt{n|x-x_n|}}$ converges for almost every $x$ with regard to Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

I tried solving by finding an integrable function such that this series is bounded below the function's integral, but I didn't find a suitable function.

Comment: You can use existence of a constant $v<\infty$ such that  $$\int_c^d \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-x_n|}}dx\leq v$$ for all $n$ and all intervals $[c,d]$ of size less than or equal to 1. I think $v = 2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing convergence of a series almost everywhere](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074685/showing-convergence-of-a-series-almost-everywhere)

Comment: The @QC_QAOA link shows a more general question and a full answer is there.  I may as well add to my above hint in a way that is not in that link: For any $\alpha>1/2$ and any $c$ we have by **Fubini-Tonelli for integration of nonnegative functions**: $$ \int_c^{c+1}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1/2+\alpha}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-x_n|}}dx = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{1/2+\alpha}}\int_c^{c+1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x-x_n|}}dx \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{n^{1/2+\alpha}}<\infty$$ so the integrand is finite for almost all $x \in [c,c+1]$. It holds for intervals $[0,1], [1,2], [2,3]$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer: suppose $x_n$ is a sequence such that the closure of $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a null set.

Take $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\delta := \inf_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\{|x-x_n|\} > 0$. Then we have.

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{n^{\alpha} \sqrt{n |x-x_n|}} \leq \frac{1}{n^{\alpha + 1/2} \sqrt{\delta}}
\end{align*}
and hence
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha} \sqrt{n |x-x_n|}} \leq & \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha + 1/2} \sqrt{\delta}} \\
=& \frac{1}{\sqrt{\delta}} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{\alpha + 1/2}} \\
\leq& \frac{1}{\sqrt{\delta}} \left( \int_1^{\infty} x^{-\alpha-1/2}dx + 1 \right)
\end{align*}
Which converges because $\alpha > 1$.

Since this holds for any such $x$, we may conclude that the sum converges everywhere except on $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: What happens if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is the sequence of all rational numbers?  Then your value $\delta$ is zero for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: goddamn, I hadn't thought of that. I'll try to adapt the argument.

Comment: The argument works if $\{x_n\}$ is a set of isolated points but I'm not even sure the proposition is true for dense sets.

Comment: If we let $y_n$ be some enumeration of the rational numbers, and take $x_1=y_1$, $x_2=y_2$, $x_3 = y_1$, $x_4 = y_2$, $x_5 = y_3$, $x_6 = y_1$, and so forth, letting $x$ run over larger and larger portions of $y$, while always returning to the beginning, then every point in $\mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $x$, and hence the series converges nowhere.

Comment: So no, for dense sets it isn't true.

Comment: Well, it might be more complicated by that. Just because $x_n$ gets closer to irrationals doesn't mean the power of $n$ can't overpower it and make the sum converge. I think the question is deceptively tricky.

Comment: Okay, just proved that being dense is not enough to disprove the conjecture. The overall problem seems really difficult though. Also, would it be possible for you to edit your answer so that you restrict the possible $x_n$ sequences so that it works? Like, if $x_n$ is isolated it is clearly true, but what about other conditions?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: See @Michael's comment for good reasoning that shows the conjecture is true. Additionally, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1074685/showing-convergence-of-a-series-almost-everywhere) for another look at a more general problem in this vein. I'll leave the answer below up as I believe it is interesting in its own right, but it should not be looked at as anything other than an explicit example of convergence when $x_n$ is dense in the reals.

---

This is not a full answer so much as a proof that the question is more difficult than at first glance. Obviously, if $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is made up of isolated points then the conjecture is true. Indeed, even if the sequence also includes some limit points (for example $\{0\}\cup \{1/n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$) then it is still not very much work to show that the conjecture holds. However, it is less obvious whether the conjecture will hold for a sequence that is dense in the reals. It might seem like no, but in fact there are sequences which are dense in the reals for which the conjecture does hold. We present one such sequence here.

First, we have to define some constants. Let $\alpha>1$ be given and define

$$\epsilon=\alpha-1>0$$

Second, let $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be an enumeration of the rational numbers in the following manner: First, set $x_1=0$. Next, set $x_n=\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ where $b_n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Additionally,

$$|a_i|+b_i>|a_j|+b_j\Rightarrow i>j$$

$$x_n>0\Rightarrow x_{n+1}=-x_n$$

Finally, the fractions shall be in their most reduced form with no repetitions. Note that there are many sequences that satisfy this definition, but the first few terms of all of them are

$$0,\frac{1}{1},\frac{-1}{1},\frac{1}{2},\frac{-1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{-2}{3},\cdots$$

Having defined our sequence $x_n$ (or at least defined a set of sequences, each of which will work with our overall logic), let $S$ be the set of number with [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) greater than $2$. By previous results, $\overline{S}$ encompasses almost all real numbers (here $\overline{S}=\{x\in\mathbb{R}:x\not\in S\}$). Thus, if we can show the series converges for $x\in S$ then we are done. As such, let $x$ be an arbitrary real in $S$. By definition

$$|x-x_n|=\left|x-\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right|>\frac{1}{b_n^{2+2\epsilon}}$$

for all sufficiently large $b$ (after some $b^{'}$).

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1/2}\sqrt{|x-x_n|}}<K+\sum_{n=N_0}^\infty \frac{b_n^{1+\epsilon}}{n^{\alpha+1/2}}$$

where $N_0$ is defined such that $b_{N_0}=b^{'}$ and $K$ is the sum from $1$ to $N_0-1$. Now, let us put a bound on $b_n$. Define

$$\chi_n=\left\lfloor\frac{b_n}{2}\right\rfloor$$

and note that

$$\frac{\pm1}{1}$$

$$\frac{\pm1}{2}$$

$$\frac{\pm1}{3},\frac{\pm2}{3}$$

$$\vdots$$

$$\frac{\pm1}{\chi_n},\cdots,\frac{\pm(\chi_n-1)}{\chi_n}$$

all appear in the sequence before $\frac{a_n}{b_n}$ since

$$\chi_n-1+\chi_n<2\chi_n\leq b_n$$

In total, there are at least

$$2\sum_{i=1}^{\chi_n}\phi(i)<n$$

rationals in the sequence before $b_n$ (where $\phi(n)$ is the [Euler Totient Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function)). However, we know from [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/95836/error-to-sum-of-euler-phi-functions) that

$$n>2\sum_{i=1}^{\chi_n}\phi(i)\approx \frac{6\chi_n^2}{\pi^2}\approx \frac{3b_n^2}{2\pi^2}=\frac{1}{9}\cdot \frac{27b_n^2}{2\pi^2}$$

Since $\frac{27}{2\pi^2}>1$, we know that for sufficiently large $b_n$ (past some $n\geq N_1$)

$$n>\frac{1}{9}b_n^2$$

Thus, a bound for $b_n$ is

$$b_n<3\sqrt{n}$$

Putting it all together and setting $N=\max\{N_0,N_1\}$ gives us

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1/2}\sqrt{|x-x_n|}}<K+3\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{n^{\frac{1+\epsilon}{2}}}{n^{\alpha+1/2}}$$

where $K$ is the sum from $1$ to $N-1$. This is

$$=K+3\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1/2-1/2-\epsilon/2}}$$

But we defined $\epsilon$ such that

$$\epsilon=\alpha-1$$

Thus

$$=K+3\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\alpha-\frac{\alpha-1}{2}}}=K+3\sum_{n=N}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{\frac{\alpha+1}{2}}}$$

Since $\frac{\alpha+1}{2}>1$, the sum converges and we are done.

Overall, I would believe that the conjecture holds for any sequence of real numbers. The difficulty lies in the fact that if you change the definition of $x_n$ from how I defined it then you open up the possibility that the sum will diverge for certain reals with irrationality measure $2$. However, I think it would be a countable subset of $\overline{S}$ and the conjecture would still hold, but I do not know how to even begin to prove this.

Comment: What was difficult about using my hint?  It gets the full solution in one line.

Comment: Uhm, I don't understand your hint or see why it should be true. Do you have a link to a more complete explanation?

Comment: Assuming the hint, we integrate the function over $[c,d]$ to get a finite number, so the integrand is finite for almost all $x \in [c,d]$.  To get the hint just integrate $\int_{-1/2}^{1/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}dx$.

Comment: Ah, that clears it up. Thanks, editing in to look at your comment and that I think this is a duplicate of another question from a while ago