# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n \sqrt{n\vert x - x_n \vert}}$ converge a.e

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be some sequence of real numbers.

Define $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ by $$f(x):=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n\sqrt{n\vert x - x_n \vert}}$$
Denote by $D:=\{x\in\mathbb R|f(x)<\infty\}$.
Prove $m(\mathbb R \setminus D) = 0$, where $m$ is Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Does this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492315/prove-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n-alpha-sqrtn-x-x-n-converges-almost?rq=1 answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: if the expectation of a random variable is finite then it is finite almost surely. So integrate and apply Fubini.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for any $a>0,$ the integrals $\int_{-a}^a 1/\sqrt{|x_n-x|}\,dx$ are uniformly bounded. Apply the monotone convergence theorem to your series.